# Android studio LibGDX Dependancy issue

Tags: android, libgdx, dependencies

my game was working perfectly and I accidently pressed enter when i saw a poop up about dependencies.

and it ruined everything. how do I revert/undo it,  ctrl + z  doesn't work.

assets directory is gone and all images are instead on resource directory.

i have tried almost everything, do i have to delete any files?
i cant find my help on StackOverflow.
i tried  to solve it for a long time but couldn't find any solution.
is there anybody that knows how i undo the dependancy change.

because now in my "playstate" class it stands "states/playstate", i dont know why?

"playstate" is in the directory of "states" and as soon as i accidently clicked enter on dependancy on that poop up, it changed to "states/playstate"

what do i do?

```
Circular reference between projects: :android -> :core -> :android
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: i cant either use libgdx methods and all libdx methods are now turned RED

Comment: open terminal and type ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies, post output with your question.

Comment: Any gradle error or any type of error, please provide some more info.

Comment: Edited, i might just copy the classes and paste them in a new libgdx project

Comment: i would still like to know what is wrong

Comment: would be easier to reimport into android studio using gradle. Unless the problem is in your gradle file. Post your build.gradle and the output of gradlew build. because with an error without a context it is hard to guess the problem.